# Editing a row in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Good morning , I would like to know how to edit the rows in a datagridview . For example, a datagridview that contains 3 columns , where columns 1 and 3 are already filled (with data ) while column 2 contains no data , as I do to fill that column keeping the data in the other columns .

data 'm not capturing any database. I'm doing it through a datatable .

```
Column 1    Column 2     Column 3
 xxxxx                    xxxxx
 xxxxx                    xxxxx
 xxxxx                    xxxxx
```

The dataGridView this well , as I do to fill column 2 ?

```
DataTable mytable = new DataTable ( " Class Name ");
mitabla.Columns.Add (new DataColumn ( " Class Name " , typeof (string ))) ;
mitabla.Columns.Add (new DataColumn ("# Method " , typeof (string ))) ;
mitabla.Columns.Add (new DataColumn ("# lines " , typeof (int ))) ;

DataGridView1.DataSource = mytable ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using WinForms since you reference DataGridView.

You really just need to have some rows in your DataTable. I'm assuming you'd have some loop to populate those rows as shown below.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable mytable = new DataTable(" Class Name ");
        mytable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(" Class Name ", typeof(string)));
        mytable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("# Method ", typeof(string)));
        mytable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("# lines ", typeof(int)));

        // Use your own logic to fill the table with data
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = mytable.NewRow();
            dr[" Class Name "] = "class" + i;
            dr["# Method "] = "";
            dr["# lines "] = i;

            mytable.Rows.Add(dr);
        }


        dataGridView1.DataSource = mytable;
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much in advance for your reply, but that's not the problem, what hinders me is after filling these columns, is to fill the one in the center

Comment: Your DataTable should probably be a member of your Form or some other object so that you have a reference to it. Then you can update any DataRow column's value later and the DataGridView will reflect the change. You could use the same for loop in the previous example or something like foreach (DataRow dr in myTable.Rows) { dr["# Method "] = "new value"; }